# Try to creating SQLite Creating Database Insert function - Undefined name ' '. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: database, flutter, function, sqlite, debugging

I am a new flutter learner who currently learning through the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQSTgf-6hDk&t=451s. I try to define createTask() function but it exist with the error Undefined name '' start from line 43 until 64.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. I have defined the name at the bottom already but it still showing the message red line, anyone can please help me identify the error and suggestion to solving it. Appreciate those help, thank you.

Below are the code attachment:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatabaseAlreadyOpenException implements Exception {}

class UnableToGetDocumentException implements Exception {}

class DatabaseIsNotOpenException implements Exception {}

class CouldNotDeleteUserException implements Exception {}

class UserAlreadyExistException implements Exception {}

class CouldNotFindUserException implements Exception {}

class TaskService {
  Database? _db;
  

  Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpenException();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseTask> createTask({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);

    // make sure owner exists in the database with the correct id
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUserException();
    }

    // create the task
    final noteId = await db.insert(taskTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      titleColumn: title,
      noteColumn: note, 
      isCompletedColumn: isCompleted, 
      dateColumn: date, 
      startTimeColumn: startTime,
      endTime: endTime, 
      color: color, 
      remind: remind, 
      repeat: repeat
    });

    final task = DatabaseTask(
    id: noteId, 
    userId: owner.id, 
    title: title, 
    note: note, 
    isCompleted: isCompleted, 
    date: date, 
    startTime: startTime, 
    endTime: endTime, 
    color: color, 
    remind: remind, 
    repeat: repeat,
    );
    return task;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final results = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (results.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUserException();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final results = await db.query(userTable,
        limit: 1, where: 'email = ?', whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()]);
    if (results.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExistException();
    }
    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
    });
    return DatabaseUser(id: userId, email: email);
  }

   Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
     final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
     final deletedCount = await db.delete(
     userTable,
     where: 'email = ?',
     whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
     );
     if(deletedCount != 1){
       throw CouldNotDeleteUserException();
     }
   }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpenException();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
    }
    try {
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;

      await db.execute(createUserTable);

      await db.execute(createTaskTable);

    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentException();
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;

  const DatabaseUser({required this.id, required this.email});

  // read hash table for every row, every user inside the database represented by object of map of String and an optional object
  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email = $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  // id is primary key of class
  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseTask {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final String note;
  final int isCompleted;
  final String date;
  final String startTime;
  final String endTime;
  final int color;
  final int remind;
  final String repeat;

  DatabaseTask(
      {required this.id,
      required this.userId,
      required this.title,
      required this.note,
      required this.isCompleted,
      required this.date,
      required this.startTime,
      required this.endTime,
      required this.color,
      required this.remind,
      required this.repeat});

  DatabaseTask.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColumn] as int,
        userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
        title = map[titleColumn] as String,
        note = map[noteColumn] as String,
        isCompleted = map[isCompletedColumn] as int,
        date = map[dateColumn] as String,
        startTime = map[startTimeColumn] as String,
        endTime = map[endTimeColumn] as String,
        color = map[colorColumn] as int,
        remind = map[remindColumn] as int,
        repeat = map[repeatColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Task, ID = $id, userID =$userId , title = $title, note = $note, isCompleted = $isCompleted, date = $date, startDate = $startTime, endTime = $endTime, color = $color, remind = $remind, repeat = $repeat';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseTask other) => id == other.id;

  // id is primary key of class
  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'tasks.db';
const taskTable = 'task';
const userTable = 'user';
const idColumn = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const titleColumn = 'title';
const noteColumn = 'note';
const isCompletedColumn = 'isCompleted';
const dateColumn = 'date';
const startTimeColumn = 'startTime';
const endTimeColumn = 'endTime';
const colorColumn = 'color';
const remindColumn = 'remind';
const repeatColumn = 'repeat';
 const createUserTable = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "email" STRING NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
      );
      ''';
  const createTaskTable = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tasks" (
        "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "user_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "title" STRING,
        "note"  STRING,
        "isCompleted"   INTEGER,
        "date"  STRING,
        "startTime" STRING,
        "endTime"   STRING,
        "color" INTEGER,
        "remind"    INTEGER,
        "repeat"    STRING,
        FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id"),
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
      );
      ''';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIRKo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFtsT.png)

I have try to rewrite but still give the same outcome. The red line only gone when you write back same name that defined previously (E.g. titleColumn: titleColumn,
noteColumn: noteColumn,). Please help me debug the error and provide the solution to me. Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWe1s.png)

Answer (score 0):

these properties are not defined in the class `TaskService`, they are defined in the class `DatabaseTask`

you can define them in the `TaskService` too, or give it as parameter in the `createTask` method. But anyway you need to set the value somewhere to set the values in the insert statement and in `DatabaseTask` constructor.

Comment: I not too understanding your meaning. Can you help to modify the code and paste in here. Appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: if you don't understand the meaning of "where to i get my data", then there is a fundamental understanding of programming missing.

Comment: If I declare the properties in Task service it will be static const or declare as var? But if declare as static it will become private properties, right? If I declare as var what are the differences with those properties and constructor that I declared in own class DatabaseTask  instead of declare another var in class TaskService?

Comment: If I declare as parameter in createTask do I need to include the class (E.g.  Future<DatabaseTask> createTask({required DatabaseUser owner, required DatabaseTask title}) async { } OR access it directly without the class  Future<DatabaseTask> createTask({required DatabaseUser owner, required title}) async { }) ?

Comment: you can, in `createTask`, add a parameter with `DatabaseTask` and then use this parameter to set the properties.